# One-To-Many Relationship (two "Many" tables)

Tags: sql, database-design

I have the following tables (a bit shortened). Now I'm wondering how I can release the "1-to-Many" Relationship between Company and  Maintenance_SystemCheck/ Maintenance_HardwareCheck.

Info: it's possible that a company might have both checks, one of either or none.

```
Company
-------
company_id    company_name       street           country
1             Comp Inc.          Main Street      Canada


Maintenance_SystemCheck
-------
SysCheck_ID    date         commands                 commands_check   
1              20.08.16     wrkactjob;wrksystm       1;0
2              21.08.16     wrkactjob;wrksystm       1;1
3              22.08.16     wrkactjob;wrksystm       1;0
4              23.08.16     wrkactjob;wrksystm       0;0


Maintenance_HardwareCheck
-------
HwCheck_ID    date         commands                 commands_check   
1              20.08.16     fans;cleaning            1;1
2              21.08.16     fans;cleaning            1;1
3              22.08.16     fans;cleaning            0;0
4              23.08.16     fans;cleaning            0;0
```

**EDIT**

My question was a bit unclear, here a full overview about my database schema.
I want to store the data records, which I have mentioned above.

Is this structure okay for that? Or would you do it in another way?

[image: Database-Schema]

If you need more information, just comment below.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean/ask - but are you asking if you can just put company_id on the two other tables as a foreign key?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen I was thinking about that, would that be the right way?

Comment: It is how you usually model simple 1-* relationships, unless something else is going on.

Comment: Usually? Thats normally not my range of area, but I have to design it. How would you solve it?

Comment: I'd do it that way if there's nothing special about the relationship.

Comment: Too many unknowns for me.  Are these 3 tables all "Master Data" meaning not transactional?  Do you just need two more tables `company_SystemCheck`, `Company_HardwareCheck` so you know which companies instituted which checks? or are all companies always implementing all checks and you just need to record the results?  Don't mix transactional data with Master data!

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please use proper technical terms. Eg it is not clear what you mean by 'release'. Please explain your problem/context then your solution (so far and/or desired) in terms of it. In particular when you refer to something be clear about what you are referring to. Eg it is not clear what you mean by 'the "1-to-Many" Relationship between Company and Maintenance_SystemCheck/ Maintenance_HardwareCheck'.

Comment: firstly, you should make the relationship clearly.One to many or Many to many?